# How to detect UITouch location visible in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitouch

I am trying to detect a `UITouch` event visible.When touch event begins.Currently, I am using below code to detect the touch location.From below code,I can able to print the touch location.Any,help would be greatly appreciated.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position :CGPoint = touch.location(in: view)
        print(position.x)
        print(position.y)
    }
}
```

**Note:** I am not trying to draw a line or anything like a  drawing app.I,Just want to see the touch event visibly.When happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to draw a circle or something to indicate where the touch is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a circle or something to appear when the user taps the screen, try this:

```
var touchIndicators: [UIView] = []
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: view)
        let touchIndicator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: location.x - 10, y: location.y - 10, width: 20, height: 20))
        touchIndicator.alpha = 0.5
        touchIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        touchIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        self.view.addSubview(touchIndicator)
        touchIndicators.append(touchIndicator)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for indicator in touchIndicators {
        indicator.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    touchIndicators = []
}
```

Pretty straightforward. Add circular views when the user touches the screen and remove them when the user lifts his/her fingers. You can also do this using `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Thanks mate. code works.I am trying to implement your answer in `touchMoved` function but touchIndicator moves all over the view as expected.i wondering how do i make the touchIndicator(one circle) just follow the finger...

Comment: @Joe if you want to do that, then just remove the for in loop and replace `touch` with `touches.first!` and change the array to a single UIView instance. In touchesMoved, set the frame of it to the new position